# Spring Cloud Streaming - Separate Connection for Producer & Consumer

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

I have a Spring Cloud Streaming transformer application using RabbitMQ.  It is reading from a Rabbit queue, doing some transformation, and writing to a Rabbit exchange.  I have my application deployed to PCF and am binding to a Rabbit service.

This works fine, but now I am needing a separate connection for consuming and producing the message.  (I want to read from the Rabbit queue using one connection, and write to a Rabbit exchange using a different connection).  How would I configure this?  Is it possible to bind my applications to 2 different Rabbit services using 1 as the producer and 1 as the consumer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, starting with version `1.3` Rabbit Binder indeed creates a separate `ConnectionFactory` for producers: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Ditmars.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_rabbitmq_binder

> Starting with version 1.3, the `RabbitMessageChannelBinder` creates an internal `ConnectionFactory` copy for the non-transactional producers to avoid dead locks on consumers when shared, cached connections are blocked because of Memory Alarm on Broker.

So, maybe that is just enough for you as is after upgrading to Spring Cloud Stream Ditmars.

**UPDATE**

> How would I go about configuring this internal ConnectionFactory copy with different connection properties?

No, that's different story. What you need is called `multi-binder` support: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Ditmars.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-binders

You should declare several blocks for different connection factories:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.binder=rabbit1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.binder=rabbit2

...

spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: foo
          binder: rabbit1
        output:
          destination: bar
          binder: rabbit2
      binders:
        rabbit1:
          type: rabbit
          environment:
            spring:
              rabbitmq:
                host: <host1>
        rabbit2:
          type: rabbit
          environment:
            spring:
              rabbitmq:
                host: <host2>
```

Comment: How would I go about configuring this internal ConnectionFactory copy with different connection properties?